Do I need to push a file if I upload it directly on GitHub Web?
If I upload a file directly through GitHub Web and commit it there, do I still need to push it, or is it already fully saved in the repository?
I uploaded a file directly through GitHub's Web interface. After selecting the file and clicking "Commit changes.

No.
When you upload or edit a file directly through GitHub's web interface, you generally have two options:

Commit directly to the branch-name branch, or
Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request

Whichever option you pick, this will either create a new commit on the origin directly to the current branch, or create a new branch on the origin. You don't need to push this change as it's being done directly on the origin, but if you've cloned the repository anywhere else, you will still need to git pull the changes back in order to see them.
